# Toolbox objects not recognized in .cs file

Tags: asp.net

I am new in asp. I have build a website using asp. I build the templete using Artisteer.
Everything works fine untill the time I was trying to make a login page. I'll give parts of my code not to bother a lot

Here is one part of my Registration.aspx page

```
<@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/design/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeFile="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Registration" %>

<@ Import Namespace="Artisteer" %>

<@ Register TagPrefix="artisteer" Namespace="Artisteer" %>

<@ Register TagPrefix="art" TagName="DefaultMenu" Src="DefaultMenu.ascx" %> 

<@ Register TagPrefix="art" TagName="DefaultHeader" Src="DefaultHeader.ascx" %> 

<@ Register TagPrefix="art" TagName="DefaultSidebar1" Src="DefaultSidebar1.ascx" %>


asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">Once Upon a Cake</asp:Content>

asp:Content ID="MenuContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
    <art:DefaultMenu ID="DefaultMenuContent" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">

art:DefaultHeader ID="DefaultHeader" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

asp:Content ID="SideBar1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Sidebar1ContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
art:DefaultSidebar1 ID="DefaultSidebar1Content" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="SheetContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="SheetContentPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">


    <artisteer:article ID="Article2" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>

       <br />

        <table class="art-article" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td><asp:TextBox ID="textBoxUser" runat="server" Width="240" MaxLength="15" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
          <td>
          <td>
```

..........

and the Registration.aspx.cs file is

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using System.Configuration;


public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page

{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string cmdStr = "Select coun (*) from Register where UserName='" + textBoxUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand userExist = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32(userExist.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User Name already Exist!!! </br> Choose another");
            }
        }


    }
```

The problem is that textBoxUser is not recognized in .cs file.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: can you see Article2 object in .cs file?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Article (or Block) is templated control. 
So you cannot refer to controls inside ContentTemplate directly from page. 
You should find this control within Article's context.

Try to add the following code to the Article class

```
public override Control FindControl(string id) 
{ 
EnsureChildControls(); 
if (null != _contentPlaceholder && _contentPlaceholder.Controls[0] is TemplateContainer) 
return _contentPlaceholder.Controls[0].FindControl(id); 

return null; 
}
```

and then you can refer to your controls like this:

```
TextBox txt = Article2.FindControl("textBoxUser") as TextBox;
```

Reference : [Artisteer Forums](http://www.artisteer.com/?post_id=162424&p=forum_post)